# How to customize font size and color in Jelly Bean?

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, customization, fonts

The combination of small font size, low contrast color schemes (gray on gray), and the erratic operation of the auto-intensity makes the screen difficult to read in many circumstances.

I like auto-dimming, but I think it follows the wrong curve and is often too dim for the ambient conditions. The only alternative is to disable the automatic function entirely, which still results in often having the wrong brightness.

Can anyone recommend the simplest approach to customizing the font sizes and colors for the JB user interface? I liked Gingerbread's UI, but would prefer stick with the JB OS if the UI could be made more like GB.

(Phone is Nexus S 9020, Jelly Bean 4.1.2)

Comment: power control widget lets you quickly switch between three brightness levels.

Comment: When dealing with an automatic feature that is IMHO very useful, and that "almost works", I'm the type of person who wants to find a way to fix it, rather than give it up entirely and use a manual method.   I'm hoping somebody will say "oh, the auto brigheness curve is in file abc.xyz, just edit the table there"

Comment: Also worth a look: [Spare Parts Plus](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.droidgram.spareparts). Amongst others, it lets you adjust the font size.

Answer (score 1):

You can go to Settings > Display > Font size, to change the size. I'm not sure how to change the color though.

Answer (score 0):

To change font size you can navigate to Settings - > Display - > Font Size.